# WP7 Location Services Accuracy in Background

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, location

I've been experimenting with running location services in WP7 using background periodic tasks. I've been testing the accuracy values (Default and High) I can specify on GeoCoordinateWatcher and I was hoping I could get some feedback from people who have dealt with similar issues. I was running the background agent with location services under Default accuracy and was able to get maybe 3 or 4 location updates throughout the day.  I would have preferred getting more frequent position updates. Would a higher accuracy (by using GPS with High accuracy) help with this?

I'm concerned that by increasing accuracy, the 25 second time limit set on periodic tasks could become a problem. Has someone run location services in background using a high accuracy? Has it impacted location update frequency? Any problems staying under the 25 seconds?  Is there a penalty on the app if the OS has to shut down the periodic task several times for taking longer than 25 seconds? Will I need to relaunch my app to get the periodic task running again?

Any advice or feedback on the subject will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[See this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> GeoCoordinateWatcher: This API, used for obtaining the geographic
>   coordinates of the device, is supported for use in background agents,
>   but it uses a cached location value instead of real-time data. The
>   cached location value is updated by the device every 15 minutes.

Given the location is cached and up to 15 mins old, I'm pretty sure specifying high accuracy isn't going to help.

Comment: Considering a background task only runs every 30 minutes, a higher level of precision wouldn't make sense anyway. Regardless, in my experience High Accuracy works just fine in background tasks.